# Can't connect to SQL Server with node server

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I wish to attempt to connect to my SQL Server database with my node server, but I have this error:

> Port for SQLEXPRESS not found in localhost

```
class DAO {
    constructor() {
        this.sqlConfig = {
            user: 'user',
            password: 'pwd',
            server: 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS',
            database: 'Test',
            port: 1433
        }
    }

    async connect() {
        try {
            console.log("Connecting database.....");
            let pool = await sql.connect(this.sqlConfig);

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

I already configured TCP/IP with SQL Server Configuration Manager and SQL Browser services. I really don't see where could come from this error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is SQL Server Browser doesn't respond with the server's port. You need to enable the TCP on your SQL Server.
You need to set the configuration for TCP/IP on the following path.

> Sql Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration >
>   Protocols for SQLSERVER > TCP/IP

If you can't find Sql Server Configuration Manager on localhost, I believe it should be at

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc

Make sure to restart the server after modification. I hope this helps.

Comment: @CamilleChlc have you restarted server after enabling TCP?

Comment: Yes, several times

Comment: try replacing localhost with the 127.0.0.1 or computer name

Comment: @CamilleChlc Have you checked, Is port already being used or available?

Comment: you can try this way also, var config = {
userName: 'test01',
password: 'test01',
server: 'localhost',
options: {
"database":"TestDB",
"instanceName": "SQL2012"
}
};